# How to enable browser vsync on Linux arm?

Tags: browser, gpu

I'm playing an [Odroid-C2](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php) and I'm having a hard time trying find a linux + browser combination that will work with vsync enabled.

So far I've tested using [this distribution of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:c2_ubuntu_release_note_v1.2) which should have the Mali GPU X11 driver installed.

I've tried launching Chromium/Firefox prefix with `FORCE_VSYNC=1` as seen in [this post](http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=136&t=21348&p=142504&hilit=vsync%20browser#p142504) but I can still see tearing.

What's the simplest way to get tear free/vsync enabled browser working on Linux on an ARM device ? (I had success with Chrome on Android, but would love to use Linux instead)